# Write keys into the Windows registry in C#

Tags: c#, windows, registry

We are trying to add a key value pair into the Windows registry using C#.

The key to write is an Environment variable for another user. The user will be a Service User, and never log on.

We have been able to get the user SID, and add it to the Registry, by P/Invoking `LoadUserProfile`.

However, when trying to write to the Environment Sub Key there is a problem:

```
        using (var key = Registry.Users.OpenSubKey(userSid + "\\Environment"))
        {
            if (key == null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Key was null (typical)");
                return;
            }

            key.SetValue("A", "B");
        }
```

This throws an *UnauthorizedAccessException* with the really helpful message

> Cannot write to the registry key

The application is running as an administrator.

For obvious reasons I am guessing it is something to do with the security access control.  I can get the access control, using `var security = key.GetAccessControl();` However, I don't know what values to change to be able to write to the Environment.

Just for the record, I can write values to some other keys such as `HKEY_USERS` itself, or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` itself, but I cannot write to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Public` for example.

Here is the stack trace if it helps:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Cannot write to the registry key.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowUnauthorizedAccessException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.EnsureWriteable()
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.SetValue(String name, Object value, RegistryValueKind valueKind)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.SetValue(String name, Object value)
   at TestingEnvVariables.Form1.GetVariablesButtonClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: Does the application is running "Run As Admin". If not, please try that. It looks like, you don't have permissions to write.

Comment: @MuralidharanDeenathayalan - yes, it is running in "Run as Admin"

Comment: Try impersonating the user, using the same user token you obtained in order to call `LoadUserProfile`.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - I tried that.  That did not allow me to write to the registry, and when I tried using Environment.SetEnvrionmentVariable it set the variable in my ordinary user profile

Comment: When you try to do it manually with `regedit`: does it fail too, or succeed?

Comment: @BernhardHiller - it succeeds manually.

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151074/setting-registry-key-write-permissions-using-net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bingo!

From the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9f66s0a(v=vs.110).aspx) on `RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String)`:

> Retrieves a subkey as read-only.

You need `RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String, Boolean)` ([MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xthy8s8d(v=vs.110).aspx)):

> Retrieves a specified subkey, and specifies whether write access is to be applied to the key.

Comment: That's it! What an idiot I am! Elementary mistake!  Thanks Harry Johnston.